# CountTimer cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, timer

I have a problem when trying to code the timer for Minesweeper. Basically, I have this separate timer code, and in this code, I declared CountTimer ct outside the constructor, and it works fine. However, when I try to do the same thing in my Minesweeper code, the compiler says that CountTimer cannot be resolved to a type. Can someone help me please?

```
//////////This is my timer code.//////////

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CountTimerGUI2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JPanel pan1 = new JPanel ();

  JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel ();

  JButton start = new JButton ("Start");
  JButton stop = new JButton ("Stop");
  CountTimer ct;

  public CountTimerGUI2 () {
    pan1.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
    timeLabel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder ());
    pan1.add (timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    start.addActionListener (this);
    stop.addActionListener (this);

    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel ();
    pan2.setLayout (new GridLayout ());

    pan2.add (start);
    pan2.add (stop);

    pan1.add (pan2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setContentPane (pan1);
    setVisible (true);
    pack ();

    ct = new CountTimer ();
  }

  private void setTimerText (String sTime) {
    timeLabel.setText (sTime);
  }

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource ();

    if (button.equals (start)) {
      ct.start ();
    }

    else if (button.equals (stop)) {
      ct.stop ();
    }
  }

  public static void main (String args []) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
      public void run () {
        new CountTimerGUI2 ();
      }
    });
  }

  private class CountTimer implements ActionListener {
    private static final int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean isTimerActive = false;
    private Timer timer = new Timer (ONE_SECOND, this);

    public CountTimer () {
      count = 0;
      setTimerText (TimeFormat (count));
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
      if (isTimerActive) {
        count++;
        setTimerText (TimeFormat (count));
      }
    }

    public void start () {
      count = 0;
      isTimerActive = true;
      timer.start ();
    }

    public void stop () {
      timer.stop ();
    }
  }

  private String TimeFormat (int count) {
    int hours = count / 3600;
    int minutes = (count - hours * 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = count - minutes * 60;

    return String.format ("%02d", hours) + " : " + String.format ("%02d", minutes) + " : " + String.format ("%02d", seconds);
  }
}

//////////This is my Minesweeper code.//////////

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
//import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.io.*;
//import java.io.FileWriter;
//import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class Minesweeper extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  public static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
  public static Random random = new Random ();

  JPanel pan1 = new JPanel ();
  JPanel pan2 = new JPanel ();
  JPanel pan3 = new JPanel ();
  JPanel pan1_1 = new JPanel ();
  JPanel pan1_2 = new JPanel ();
  JPanel pan1_3 = new JPanel ();
  JPanel pan1_3_D = new JPanel ();

  JButton button [][];
  JButton Save = new JButton ("Save");
  JButton Load = new JButton ("Load");
  JButton New = new JButton ("New");
  JButton One = new JButton ("1");
  JButton Two = new JButton ("2");
  JButton Three = new JButton ("3");
  JButton R = new JButton ("R");

  JLabel instruction = new JLabel ("Instruction Panel");//changeable
  JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel ();
  JLabel score = new JLabel ("Score");//it is only temporary

  CountTimer ct;

  public Minesweeper (int row, int column) {
    button = new JButton [row][column];

    GridLayout gl_pan1 = new GridLayout (1, 3);
    GridLayout gl_pan2 = new GridLayout (row, column);
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout (2, 1);//gl is for the 3 sub-panels in pan1
    GridLayout gl_pan1_3_D = new GridLayout (1, 4);

    pan1.setLayout (gl_pan1);
    pan2.setLayout (gl_pan2);
    pan1_1.setLayout (gl);
    pan1_2.setLayout (gl);
    pan1_3.setLayout (gl);
    pan1_3_D.setLayout (gl_pan1_3_D);

    setTitle ("Minesweeper");

    JPanel frameBorder = (JPanel)getContentPane ();
    frameBorder.setLayout (new BoxLayout (getContentPane (), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    frameBorder.setBorder (new BevelBorder (BevelBorder.LOWERED));

    pan1.setBorder (new EtchedBorder (EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    pan2.setBorder (new EtchedBorder (EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    pan3.setBorder (new EtchedBorder (EtchedBorder.LOWERED));

    Save.setMinimumSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    Save.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    Save.setMaximumSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    Load.setMinimumSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    Load.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    Load.setMaximumSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    New.setMinimumSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    New.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (25, 50));
    New.setMaximumSize (new Dimension (25, 50));

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
        button [r][c] = new JButton ();
        button [r][c].setMinimumSize (new Dimension (20, 40));
        button [r][c].setPreferredSize (new Dimension (20, 40));
        button [r][c].setMaximumSize (new Dimension (20, 40));
        pan2.add (button [r][c]);
        //button [r][c].addActionListener (this);
      }
    }

    pan1_1.add (Save);
    pan1_1.add (Load);
    pan1_2.add (timeLabel);
    pan1_2.add (score);
    pan1_3.add (New);
    pan1_3_D.add (One);
    pan1_3_D.add (Two);
    pan1_3_D.add (Three);
    pan1_3_D.add (R);
    pan1_3.add (pan1_3_D);

    /*Save.addActionListener (this);
     Load.addActionListener (this);
     New.addActionListener (this);
     One.addActionListener (this);
     Two.addActionListener (this);
     Three.addActionListener (this);
     R.addActionListener (this);*/

    pan1.add (pan1_1);
    pan1.add (pan1_2);
    pan1.add (pan1_3);
    pan3.add (instruction);

    frameBorder.add (pan1);
    frameBorder.add (pan2);
    frameBorder.add (pan3);

    setContentPane (frameBorder);
    pack ();
    setVisible (true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

  }

  public static void main (String args []) throws Exception {
    int row = 10;
    int column = 10;

    new Minesweeper (row, column);

    int current_row = 5;
    int current_col = 5;
    int percentage = 10; //this is subject to change
    int number_of_mines = (int)(row*column*percentage*0.01);
    int mine_position [] = new int [number_of_mines];

    boolean revealed [][] = new boolean [row][column]; //whether the button is revealed or not
    boolean mines [][] = new boolean [row][column]; //whether there is a mine or not
    int revealed_number [][] = new int [row][column]; //the number that should appear on the revealed button

    int counter = 0; //this is for the gameEnd method
    boolean end = false; //whether the game is ended or not
}
```

Comment: check your code again, maybe i'm missing something but I didn't see the initialization of the CounterTimer variable in Minesweeper class constructor or anywhere for that matter

Comment: CounterTimer is not initialized. This is the reason timer is not working. Please initialize and correct obivious mistakes like registering actionEvents  and nesting CounterTimer class in MineSweeper class

Answer (score -1):

The name of your class is `CountTimerGUI2`, which is also how you will have to create an instance of that object:

```
CountTimerGUI2 ctGUI;
```

This should do the trick.

Note also that within `CountTimerGUI2`, you have a private class `CountTimer`. If you are trying to get access to that inner object, remove the `private` class access modifier before the declaration of that class (this will make it have package level access)...

```
class CountTimer implements ActionListener {
    ...
}
```

and then make both the `CountTimerGUI2` and `Minesweeper` classes in the same package by adding `package package_name;` at the top of both of the files.

Then you will be able to access `CountTimerGUI2`'s ct object:

```
ctGUI.ct.start();
```

Or create an instance of that inner class object within the Minesweeper class:

```
import package_name.CountTimerGUI2.CountTimer;
... 
CountTimer ct;
...
ct.start();
```

Comment: If it is private, how could you import it in static way?

Comment: If you read my response, you can see I suggest removing the private access modifier.

Comment: It's not the only problem.

Comment: What is the other problem that is not potentially being addressed?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It's fine.